# Get Characters from Float64Array

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

How i can get from a `Long` value an array of `characters` or a `String`?

My first thinking was `Float64Array` because, `JavaScript` don't know longer values after 53bits and an bit-shifting for long values need 56bit like:

```
this.writeByte(value >>> 56);
this.writeByte(value >>> 48);
this.writeByte(value >>> 40);
this.writeByte(value >>> 32);
this.writeByte(value >>> 24);
this.writeByte(value >>> 16);
this.writeByte(value >>> 8);
this.writeByte(value);
```

I wan't a result from the `Long`-Value `-736340139`. The original hex value is

> **HEX:** FF FF FF FF FF FF D0 3F
>
> **RAW:** ÿÿÿÿÿÿÐ

When i'm using `Float64Array`, im getting following results:

> new Float64Array([ -736340139 ]);

[image: Output]

How i can..

**A)** access the buffer-values like `Int8Array`, `Int16Array`, `Int32Array` and `Uint8Array`?

**B)** create an "Long" String there contains the Value `-736340139` with the RAW-Output `ÿÿÿÿÿÿÐ?` (or in HEX `FF FF FF FF FF FF D0 3F`)?

Comment: If you already know that JS cannot represent it as a number, what do you mean by "a Long value"?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, what is your real problem? Are you trying to implement your own Bignum library?

Comment: @Bergi with `Long`-Value, i mean a `Long`-Value. Reference from Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html - **Yes**, i know, that `Java` is not `JavaScript`! And JavaScript has'nt `Long` as DataType.

Comment: So if you know that JS doesn't have a `Long` type, what kind of value do you want to pass?!